# Office 2013 disable account change

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

I've setup office 2013 with an Office 365 account.

I'd like to lock the account settings and disable change account.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally found it...

I downloaded the group policy .admx files. They come with an Excel file where you can find the settings and the corresponding register key

I've created these keys:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Licensing
HideManageAccountLink 1 

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\SingIn
SignInOptions 3
```

These keys hidden the link to change account or logoff disappears and the button Manage Account in the File>Options>Account

Thank you